# vuejs how to dynamically change data in the object

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got an array as below:

```
return {
   address: 'London'
   telephone: '0044 345 6576 543422'
   items: [
      {active: true, text: 'Company address: xyz, other info1'},
      {active: true, text: 'Company telephone: xyz, other info2,'},
      {active: true, text: 'text3'},
      {active: true, text: 'text4'},
      {active: true, text: 'text5'}
      ...
   ]
}
```

My intention is to output array in template as html. My array is some kind of reusable template, so I need somehow to output the right data.

I tried to use computed property with `${this.address}` but with no luck.

Can anyone more experienced show me how to do it?

edit:

```
<template>
  <div v-for="item in items">
     {{item.text}}
  </div>
</template>
```

this should show 'Company address: London, other info1, Company telephone: 0044 345 6576 543422, other info2, text3, ...' .

Comment: this is an object, not an array

Comment: Can you show us your desired output?

Comment: @Occam'sRazor you're right

Comment: Are you going for something like this? https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/NyeGmN?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert this is closer to the answer, but not really: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gvZaVO?editors=1010
I expect: `Company address: London, next information in the text
Company telephone: 0044 345 6576 543422`

Comment: More like this then? https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/NyeGmN?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert Yes, just like this. This is the answer. Thank you, I would never solve this out... :)

Comment: @Bert now I need to find out how to make it with multiple placeholders within one `item[i].text` :)

Comment: That's doable; you'll likely need to change dataField to an array and come up with a better placeholder system.

Comment: @Bert this seems to be too complicated for me. but I will think about it. Your approach is correct and I will follow it. I will better choose computed property and transform the Object into new one.

Comment: @Bert could I kindly ask you for an example of multiple placeholder :) It seems to be too difficult for me at this level of knowledge, but will be great example to learn from

Comment: Here is an example. `data` is an array of the data properties that should replace each of the placeholders. The placeholders are now `{0}` or `{1}` etc based on the position in the data array. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/MQZNpE?editors=1010

Comment: @Bert Thank you! I'll try to analyze and implement it

Comment: @Bert I've made it! :) Thank you for a great start point!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, the issue here is that you want to replace part of the text in each item with a data value. In order to do that, you need to know what to replace it with, and where to put it.

Here is a very basic example of one way you might do that.

```js
console.clear()

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data(){
    return {
      address: 'London',
      telephone: '0044 345 6576 543422',
      items: [
      {active: true, text: 'Company address: [placeholder], other info1', dataField: 'address'},
      {active: true, text: 'Company telephone: [placeholder], other info2,', dataField: 'telephone'},
      {active: true, text: 'text3'},
      {active: true, text: 'text4'},
      {active: true, text: 'text5'}
      ]
    }
  },
  computed:{
    activeItems(){
      return this.items.filter(item => item.active === true)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getInterpolatedText(text, field) {return text.replace("[placeholder]", this[field])}
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.4.2"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="item in activeItems">
    {{getInterpolatedText(item.text, item.dataField)}}
  </div>
</div>
```

In this example, I added the text `[placeholder]` in each string for the place where you want to insert the text (but it could be *any* pattern, just something that is serving as a placeholder for where you will insert the text). I also added a property to each item, `dataField`, that defines what data property to use to replace the placeholder text.

Comment: your approach is great, when I use it for simple variables, when I use it on arrays I got undefined: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oEJxWz?editors=1011, edit: solved

Comment: If you're going to use deep properties like that, you'll be best off using a library like lodash. https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/jZXqpR?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

Please this is not an array at all. This structure is more of an object .In this you should separate all of your identifiers by a ","(comma).so you should have

```
    return{
   address: 'London',
   telephone: '0044 345 6576 543422',
   items: [
      {active: true, text: 'Company address: xyz'},
      {active: true, text: 'Company telephone: xyz'},
      {active: true, text: 'text3'},
      {active: true, text: 'text4'},
      {active: true, text: 'text5'}
   ]
}
```

And to access data let's say address we use:

```
this.address;//to access address
this.items[0].text;
```

where 0 is the index of the items object and [this](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp) refers to the global created object